# How to pass array of strings between javascript and C/C++ code with webassembly/emscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to write a web application that will do sort of word processing (say spell check, grammar check, word analysis) using back-end C/C++ code. (I have got c/C++ code working in another desktop app... I want to bring it to web).
I want an example minimal code doing this (**pass array of strings** from JavaScript to c/c++ code...c/c++ code will do the word operations... I have this code ......and **the resulting array of strings** will be sent back to JavaScript where they will be processed further. (passing **arrays** to and from is important)
Please point me to any such code/tutorial, from where I can make a start.

I searched GitHub. I found several projects using emscripten but could not get this anywhere. (Only place I could get some clue was Hunspell built with emscripten ... however I could not build it successfully)

Please let me know . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First prepare the C++ side to receive a string (character array):

```
static char *string_buffer = NULL;
static size_t string_length = 0;

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE string_start_js(void) {}
void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE string_final_js(void) {}

char * EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE string_ensure(size_t length) 
{ 
  // ensure that the buffer is long enough
  if (length <= string_length) return string_buffer;

  // grow the buffer
  char *new_buffer = realloc(string_buffer, length + 1);

  // handle the out of memory
  if (new_buffer == null) return NULL;

  // remember
  string_buffer = new_buffer;
  string_length = length;

  // done
  return string_buffer;
}

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE string_handle(size_t length)
{
  // sanity
  if (string_buffer == NULL || length > string_length) halt;

  // terminate
  string_buffer[length] = 0;

  // work with the string characters, store/process it 
}

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE string_clear(void)
{
  // friendly
  if (string_buffer == NULL) return;

  // free
  free(string_buffer);

  // remember
  string_buffer = NULL;
  string_length = 0;
}
```

From the JavaScript side send one string to the C++ side:

```
let strings = ["abc", "defg", "1"];

// inform the C++ side that some strings are going to be transferred
exports['string_start_js']();

// send all strings
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) 
{
  // single string to transport
  let string = strings[i];

  // convert to a byte array
  let string_bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(string);

  // ensure enough memory in the C++ side
  let string_offset = exports["string_ensure"](string_bytes.byteLength);

  // handle the out of memory 
  if (string_offset == 0) throw "ops...";

  // have view of the instance memory
  let view = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, string_offset, string_bytes.byteLength);

  // copy the string bytes to the memory
  view.set(string_bytes);

  // handle 
  exports['string_handle'](string_bytes.byteLength);
}

// inform the C++ side that all strings were transferred 
exports['string_final_js']();

// clear the used buffer
exports['string_clear']();
```

The way from C++ to WASM can be more simple:

- have a character array (pointer) and its length
- call an import function to give the array pointer to JavaScript and its length
- make a `view` of the memory
- read the characters from the `view`

Something like this in the C++ side:

```
extern "C" {
  extern void string_start_cpp(void);
  extern void string_final_cpp(void);
  extern void string_fetch(char *pointer, size_t length);
}

void foo(void)
{
  // inform the JavaScript side that 
  string_start_cpp();

  // runtime string
  const char *demo = "abc";

  // send to JavaScript
  string_fetch(demo, strlen(demo));

  // inform the JavaScript side all strings were send
  string_final_cpp();
}
```

And in JavaScript supply the functions during the instance creation:

```
string_start_cpp: function(offset, length) 
{
  console.log("{");
},
string_final_cpp: function(offset, length) 
{
  console.log("}");
},
string_fetch: function(offset, length) 
{
  // view the bytes
  let view = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, offset, length); 

  // convert the UTF-8 bytes to a string
  let string = new TextDecoder().decode(view);

  // use
  console.log(string);
}
```

I did not test the code, there could be some syntax errors. You can improve in many places the code, but the idea is what counts.